# Nothing returns after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is my Php file from where i call for a another php file using `ajax` to get some data after submit a button:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form enctype="">
            <button class="refresh"> submit </button>
            <input placeholder="text here" name="roll" >

        </form>

            <script>

                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('.refresh').click(function(){
                      //  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                        //event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'ajax.php',
                            type:'POST',
                            data:{roll:'rana'},
                            //async:false,
                            success:function(response){
                                alert(response);
                                //document.write(response);
                            },
                            cache:false,
                            contentType:false,
                            processData:false
                        });return fasle;
                    });                               
    });
            </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

another php file is:

```
<?php 
echo 'rana';
echo $_POST["roll"];
?>
```

When i write some text and click on submit button,then the text of input field show in url,and dont get any data from another php file. Why? Can anyone give me some  clue or help? Thank you.

Comment: Check out my answer below, it explains why your code didn't work and how you should do it. Please don't forget to mark it as correct answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

After you click on the button, form is submitted, you need to stop that behavior by using `preventDefault()` method. Replace your script with following:

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.refresh').click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault(); // this line will prevent submission of form
                  //  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'ajax.php',
                        type:'POST',
                       // data:{roll:'rana'},
                        //async:false,
                        success:function(response){
                            alert(response);
                            //document.write(response);
                        },
                        cache:false,
                        contentType:false,
                        processData:false
                    });return fasle;
                });                               
});
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks it is now working onlly in success response, but i can't send data and get them back after processing in php file

Comment: uncomment this line: `// data:{roll:'rana'},` and change it to `data: {roll: $('input[name="roll"]').val();},`

Comment: Using $('input[name="roll"]').val(); is slower and not recommended, using $('#roll').val() and changing name to id is better in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't receive any POST data in your `ajax.php` file because there are none, the `data` object in your ajax request is empty and commented out.

Contrary to what you'd expect, your form values can't just be sent through POST to your PHP file, similar to using `action="file.php method="post"` because in AJAX you have to manually "build" the `data` object to be sent as a POST request.

Here's how it would work:

**Form file:**

```
<form>
    <input placeholder="text here" id="string">
    <input type="submit" class="refresh" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.refresh').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'ajax.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                string: $('#string').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        }
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

**Backend file:**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['string'];
?>
```

Notice how I named the input by `id` instead of `name` and retrieved the value through `$('#string').val()` then assigned it to `string` which gets sent via the POST request. You should do the same for every input field in your form.

Also, you don't need these:

```
cache:false,
contentType:false,
processData:false
```

Because reasons.

Comment: Please mark my answer as the correct answer and upvote it so that others can't benefit from the help, and you'll also gain reputation points for doing so.